# sich drehen vs. sich kreisen

Tags: difference

What is the difference between:

> Die Erde dreht sich um die Sonne.

and:

> Die Erde kreist sich um die Sonne.

Comment: The second sentence is incomprehensible. *kreisen* is not usually used as a reflexive verb, so people won't be able to associate a canonical meaning with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Die Erde dreht sich um die Sonne.

Technically has **drehen** the meaning of **spinning** or **rotating**. But it's not uncommon to use it in everyday German also as **orbiting** or **circling around**

> Die Erde kreist um die Sonne.

**umkreisen** means **orbiting** or **circling around**.

the construct

> Die Erde kreist um sich (selbst).

actually means **spinning** or **rotating**.

Answer (score 5):

Der erste Satz ist verkürzt und enthält in Wahrheit zwei Bewegungen.

> Die Erde dreht sich (auf ihrem Weg) um die Sonne.

*Sich drehen* ist die Bewegung eines Körpers um eine innere Achse oder einen inneren Angelpunkt. Die Erde dreht sich um die Erdachse, nicht um die Sonne.

[Kreisen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kreisen) heißt, sich im Kreis bewegen. Das heißt, der Körper bewegt sich auf einem Kreis, dessen Mittelpunkt sich außerhalb des Körpers befindet. Der Körper kreist um diesen Mittelpunkt.

> Die Erde kreist <s>sich</s> um die Sonne.

Beide Sätze lassen sich zu einer eindeutigen und vollständigen Aussage zusammenfassen:

> Die Erde kreist, sich drehend, um die Sonne.

Comment: Ich hätte den ersten Satz nie so verstanden und wüßte auch nicht, daß andere ihn so verstehen. *Die Erde dreht sich um die Sonne* bedeutet *die Erde umkreist die Sonne*.

Comment: @DavidVogt Nein. Der erste Satz ist einfach falsch. Man kann mit etwas gutem Willen aber verstehen, was gemeint ist, was wenig Sinn macht, denn dazu muss man ja schon wissen, dass die Erde um die Sonne kreist. Die Erde dreht sich ... heißt die Erde dreht *sich*.

Comment: Ein downvote dafür, dass jemand nicht weiß, was *sich drehen* bedeutet, ist armselig.

Comment: Danke fur eine tolle Erklärung, nur diesen Satz:
"Man könnte beide Sätze zusammenfassen, um daraus einen richtigen zu machen", mag ich nicht. Man kann daraus schließen, dass der erste Satz falsch ist, was tatsächlich aber doch nicht so ist, oder?

Comment: @Olafang Man kann *sich drehen* oder man kann *sich um etwas drehen*. Beides funktioniert, auch im Bezug auf den Satz. Ich würde jedoch David Vogt insofern Recht geben, dass die allermeisten wirklich *"die Erde umkreist die Sonne"* verstehen.

Comment: @akuzminykh Das mag schon sein, dass die meisten das so verstehen. Die meisten benutzen auch *Dasselbe* und *das Gleiche* synonym und steigern Adjektive, die nicht steigerbar sind. Deshalb ist es trotzdem nicht richtig. Sich [drehen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/drehen) ist eine Bewegung um die eigene Achse. *Sich um etwas drehen* funktioniert nur im übertragenen Sinn.

Comment: @sermonionx Doch, der erste Satz ist falsch und wird nur verstanden, weil man schon weiß, was gemeint ist. Richtig wird er erst, wenn man die Verkürzung unterstellt.

Comment: @Olafant Vielleicht vermutlich falsch verstanden, aber doch auch unbedingt falsch? Denn, "Die Erde dreht sich" - bezieht sich auf die Bewegung um die eigene Achse, und "um die Sonne" deutet auf die Richtungsangabe hin. Also ich sehe die ganze Bedeutung in diesem Satz enthalten.

Comment: @sermonionx Dann sind wir uns doch einig. Das ist ja gerade die Verkürzung, die ich unterstelle, um ihn als richtig zu betrachten. Aber du hast schon recht: wenn ich das voraussetze, sollte es am Ende nicht heißen *um daraus einen richtigen zu machen*. Ich werde das gleich mal ändern. Vielen Dank für den Hinweis!

Comment: Ich muss @Olafant hier unbedingt rechtgeben. Wenn sich A um B dreht, so bezeichnet B die Drehachse von A. Das ist nicht dasselbe wie ein Kreisen von A um B.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Es können sich auch zwei Elemente umeinander drehen mit einer Drehachse die zwischen beiden liegt. Und der Mond dreht sich beim Kreisen um die Erde genau mit der Geschwindigkeit, mit der er sich um sich selbst dreht, so dass er uns immer die gleiche Seite zuwendet.